# How to execute a convolution with scipy only on specific locations?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution, scientific-computing

I want to apply on simple convolution, nothing fancy, on specific locations **only**. I know I could compute the whole computation and only keep the result from the desired location, however is there any way I can **not do** the unecessary calculations ?

Here is an example code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve

mat_shape = (40,40)

# input matrix that will be convolved
input_mat = np.random.randint(2, size=mat_shape).astype(np.float32)

# array([[1., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 1., 1., ..., 1., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 1., 1.],
#        ...,
#        [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 1., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 1., ..., 1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)


# create a random matrix for the convolution
bool_mat = np.random.randint(2, size=mat_shape) == 1

# array([[ True, False, False, ...,  True,  True, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True, False,  True],
#        [ True, False, False, ...,  True,  True, False],
#        ...,
#        [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True, False,  True],
#        [ True, False, False, ...,  True, False, False],
#        [ True,  True, False, ..., False, False, False]])


kernel_shape = (5, 5)
kernel_mat = np.random.random(size=kernel_shape)

# array([[0.70641424, 0.39223595, 0.68945359, 0.17829957, 0.89733021],
#        [0.58014976, 0.1798463 , 0.36159475, 0.15709205, 0.9330952 ],
#        [0.73937093, 0.34720608, 0.1095671 , 0.87423794, 0.58166474],
#        [0.18155221, 0.99321004, 0.40209741, 0.82267676, 0.59944673],
#        [0.2937129 , 0.88619991, 0.7936567 , 0.88069129, 0.67562886]])

rslt_mat = convolve(input_mat, kernel_mat, mode='constant')

# array([[1.4857752 , 2.528183  , 3.863519  , ..., 0.81740016, 0.34470913, 0.9813053 ],
#        [2.544829  , 3.702742  , 4.2559624 , ..., 1.6619489 , 1.0067129 , 0.6005618 ],
#        [3.4930434 , 5.8310647 , 6.3238297 , ..., 3.208856  , 2.236349  , 1.3885077 ],
#        ...,
#        [2.9012854 , 4.524009  , 6.7244134 , ..., 5.1134896 , 5.108649  , 4.004656  ],
#        [2.4392862 , 5.1577754 , 6.400248  , ..., 5.9179497 , 4.807929  , 3.7523596 ],
#        [4.450597  , 5.131026  , 7.211094  , ..., 4.230295  , 4.0098715 , 2.2621353 ]], dtype=float32)
```

My objective is to use the matrix `bool_mat` containing boolean values and of the same shape than `input_mat` and apply the convolution and **compute** the result of the convolution operation **only** on the location `bool_mat == True`.

Btw. I could very simply implements from scratch the convolution op, I would prefer not having to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Do you want to effectively mask your data set, or do you want to only evaluate the convolution at certain locations?

Comment: More specifically, do you want the locations at `bool_mat == False` to affect the result of the convolution?

Comment: @DanielLenz The values where `bool_mat == False` should affect the result of the convolution, however the convolution should only be computed where `bool_mat == True`. However if applying a mask is much simpler, I can go with that, in my case `bool_mat == False` only when  `input_mat == 0` so it won't change anything to mask or sparsely evaluate the convolution.

Comment: @DanielLenz any idea ?

Comment: No, nothing that wouldn't require re-writing the convolution :-/

Comment: Damned ... Thanks for your help